# Python: Importing from text file into sublists

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to read a text file and have each line be a sub list with each word of the line being a different entry in that sublist for example:
line 1 hello my name is bob
line 2 hello my name is tim
I would like the list to be something like:
[[hello, my, name, is,bob],[hello, my, name, is, tim]]
`results = []
fileToProcess = open("zodiac.txt", "r")
for line in fileToProcess:
    for word in line.split():
        results.append(line.strip().split(','))
print(results)`

Answer (score 0):

You were close.  Just use split once, and split using a space instead of a comma.

```
results = []
fileToProcess = open("zodiac.txt", "r")
for line in fileToProcess:
   results.append(line.strip().split(' '))
print(results)
```

I tried it in python3 with the following text file

```
Hello my name is Bob
Hello my name is Tim
```

and got the result

```
[['Hello', 'my', 'name', 'is', 'Bob'], ['Hello', 'my', 'name', 'is', 'Tim']]
```